# Quaternion.Slerp on X and Z axis without Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Quaternion Rotation]I am trying to rotate the Player about X, Y, and Z axis.  The Y axis should not move from last angle.  Example, if I rotate 45 degree's to the left, the player should not rotate back to 0.  The players X and Z axis rotate a maximum of 30 degrees, then when Input is no longer in use, settle to 0.

Through trial and error, I have finally gotten my Y angle to not Slerp back to 0.  However, X and Z, still consider Y to be 0 degree's.  The player is rotated (assume 45 degree's to the left), but movement along X and Z is as if Y is 0 degree's.

I've been reading articles and threads, and watching video's across multiple domains, including but not limited StackOverflow, Unity forums, Unity API, and YouTube video's.

[Video of Current Game](https://youtu.be/QXe7lAmkpic) - notice the engine exhaust - X and Z never change to the new normal of the Camera view / Player Y direction.

```cs
        void Update()
    {
        if(!controller.isGrounded)
        {

            //Three degree's
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Thrust"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection *= speed;

            //rotate around Y-Axis
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * rotationSpeed, 0);
            float currentY = transform.eulerAngles.y; //save Y for later

            //rotation around X and Z
            float tiltAroundX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle;
            float tiltAroundZ = -1 * (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle);

            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(tiltAroundX, currentY, tiltAroundZ);

            Vector3 finalRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, smooth).eulerAngles;
            finalRotation.y = currentY; //reintroduce Y
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(finalRotation);

        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further research that lead me along different avenues, I discovered that there were two issues.  Both issue's revolved around the fact that the Z-axis was never being normalized to the new Y-axis degree after rotation. @Ruzihm, solved the issue of Rotation.  I solved the then visible issue of movement.  Which became readily visible once rotation was working properly.

In essence, the Z-axis (`transform.forward`) must be recalculated after any change in the Y-axis rotation (`Vector3.up`). Once you have the new normal (`transform.forward`), the movement vector needed to flattened to the plane to keep the player from diving into the surface of the world.  Thank you @Ruzihm for all your assistance.

Here is the new code:

```
//Three degree's
moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
                            Input.GetAxis("Thrust"),
                            Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

//Normalize the movement direction and flatten the Plane
moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
moveDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, Vector3.up);

moveDirection *= speed;

// collect inputs
float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * rotationSpeed;
float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle;
float roll = -1 * (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle);

// Get current forward direction projected to plane normal to up (horizontal plane)
Vector3 forwardCurrent = transform.forward
                        - Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, Vector3.up) * Vector3.up;
// Debug to view forwardCurrent
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forwardCurrent * 2, Color.white);

// create rotation based on forward
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardCurrent);

// rotate based on yaw, then pitch, then roll. 
// This order prevents changes to the projected forward direction

targetRotation = targetRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(yaw, Vector3.up);


// Debug to see forward after applying yaw
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, targetRotation * Vector3.forward, Color.red);

targetRotation = targetRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(pitch, Vector3.right);
targetRotation = targetRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(roll, Vector3.forward);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, smooth);


controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some incorrect assumptions about the order of rotations that apply when working with Euler angles.  Roll is applied, then pitch, then finally yaw. This means that keeping the same yaw then setting the roll and pitch to zero (or even just changing roll) can completely change the flattened direction you're facing.

It may help to rotate by yaw, flatten the forward direction (aka project it to a completely horizontal plane)  Then create a rotation based off that (using [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)) which you can then rotate by each axis manually.

```
if(!controller.isGrounded)
{

    //Three degree's
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 
                                Input.GetAxis("Thrust"), 
                                Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDirection *= speed;

    // collect inputs
    float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * rotationSpeed;
    float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle;
    float roll = -1 * (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle);

    // Get current forward direction projected to plane normal to up (horizontal plane)
    Vector3 forwardCurrent = transform.forward 
                            - Vector3.Dot(transform.forward,Vector3.up) * Vector3.up;

    // Debug to view forwardCurrent
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.location, forwardCurrent, Color.white, 0f, false);

    // create rotation based on forward
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardCurrent);

    // rotate based on yaw, then pitch, then roll. 
    // This order prevents changes to the projected forward direction

    targetRotation = targetRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(yaw, Vector3.up);


    // Debug to see forward after applying yaw
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.location, targetRotation * Vector3.forward, Color.red, 0f, false);

    targetRotation = targetRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(pitch, Vector3.right);
    targetRotation = targetRotation  * Quaternion.AngleAxis(roll, Vector3.forward);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, smooth);

    //debug new forward/up
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.location, Transform.forward, Color.blue, 0f, false);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.location, Transform.up, Color.green, 0f, false);

    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This may be considered a partial answer because being able to determine a "flattened forward" direction and reorder the process of applying component rotations is useful to answering your question but may not be enough to get the full effect you want depending on the details.

As a sidenote, you may want to consider using [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) instead of `Quaternion.Slerp` if you want to ensure that it will actually reach the target rotation instead of infinitely approach it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.  The information provided is very insightful. Unfortunately, utilizing the code you provided did not alter the results.  I am trying to work out a way graphically to explain the issue and desired result.  I could create a very short video, but not sure I can embed it here.

Comment: @LeePaulison if you can put the video on any hosting site for videos, then you can inline/embed the link. Unfortunately there's not good support of video on Stackoverflow.... in 2019. Maybe in 2030.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include a picture and video (posted to YouTube).  I hope they provide enough information.

Comment: @LeePaulison I changed the code to apply the yaw to the flattened forward direction and also to add some debugging rays. Let me know if that fixes the problem, but if it doesn't, could you comment with a video showing the white & red rays that get drawn?

Comment: @Ruzihm  Thank you for your help so far.  I had to make couple minor changes to the code, transform.location -> transform.position, removed the duration from the rays, and flipped the order of the Vector3.forward * targetRotation -> targetRotation * Vector3.forward.  Unity won't multiply a vector * quaternion, only a quaternion * vector.  

Here is the new video showing the rays.  The Red and White rays never change.

https://youtu.be/QRudvMy77gs