# Unity3D How can I make my player rotate towards where the camera is looking while attacking

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game is a third-person over the shoulder game (inspired by god of war). My problem is that when im moving and pressing attack the player attacks towrds which direction it is rotated at the moment. But what I want is that the player no matter which direction it's rotated when attacking it should rotate and attack towrds where the camera is looking, let's say there is an enemy right infront of us and we are looking at it with the camera but our player is looking to the right side to for example dodge an attack or running to attack from another side I don't want it to attack towards it's right in this situation I want it to rotate towards the camera direction and attack.

Thanks.

I couldn't figure out how I should approach this situation and I couldn't find any information online. Maybe I was searching for the wrong thing with the wrong keywords.

Comment: could you provide us with some code of your player controller and where you have access to get the camera info. to make the player look in the direction of the camera, just get the offset (normalised vector) of the difference from the player forward position and the camera position, then just rotate the player along the z index based on the angle between those 2 vectors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quaternion.Slerp on X and Z axis without Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878359/quaternion-slerp-on-x-and-z-axis-without-y-axis)